# Idiomatic way to get the length of a window property in X11?

Tags: c, utf-8, x11

I have just started learning X11 yesterday and I have a very hard time finding information about it.

I'd like to be able to retrieve the UTF-8 title _NET_WM_NAME of an X11 window. The problem is that you're supposed to call it with a length parameter. My current solution involves first retrieving the length of the string using `XGetWindowProperty` with 0 length parameter, and then calling `XGetWindowProperty` again using the `bytes_after_return` information for the `length`.

The problem is that this involves two allocations and frees. I'm not a super advanced programmer, but that is probably not good, right? While in practice two allocations for something small and infrequent like getting a window title probably won't make much of a difference, I hear everywhere that unnecessary allocations and frees should still be avoided.

Here is my code:

```
Atom actualType;
int actualFormat;
unsigned long nItems;
unsigned long bytesAfter;
unsigned char* prop;

XGetWindowProperty(
    display, 
    window,
    _NET_WM_NAME,
    0UL,
    0UL,
    False,
    UTF8_STRING,
    &actualType,
    &actualFormat,
    &nItems,
    &bytesAfter,
    &prop
);

XFree(prop);

XGetWindowProperty(
    display, 
    window,
    _NET_WM_NAME,
    0UL,
    (bytesAfter + 3UL) / 4UL, // Divide by four and round up
    False,
    UTF8_STRING,
    &actualType,
    &actualFormat,
    &nItems,
    &bytesAfter,
    &prop
);

printf("title: %s", prop);

XFree(prop);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

The alternative solution would just be to store the title each time it is set, but I'm not sure if it's possible for the saved and actual title to desynchronize.

Thanks ppl <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with multiple allocations if they're unavoidable, and you'd likely need to do so anyway for larger amounts of data.  Request a reasonable number of bytes and use a loop to handle the incoming data as necessary, utilizing the offset parameter to specify where to continue reading.  If `4*length` is larger than the amount of data to return, then it will only return the necessary amount of data, so you do not need to worry about calculating the correct length using the `bytesAfter` parameter:

```c
Atom actualType;
int actualFormat;
unsigned long nItems;
unsigned long bytesAfter;
unsigned char* prop;

// specify length as number of bytes divided by 4
#define MB (1048576)
long length = (64 * MB) / 4;

printf("title: ");
for (long offset = 0;; offset += length) {

    XGetWindowProperty(
        display,
        window,
        _NET_WM_NAME,
        offset,
        length,
        False,
        UTF8_STRING,
        &actualType,
        &actualFormat,
        &nItems,
        &bytesAfter,
        &prop
    );

    printf("%s", prop);
    XFree(prop);
    if (bytesAfter == 0)
        break;
}
```

Naturally you can request more data if you wish, adjusting `length` based upon `bytesAfter` as necessary, and doing so is indeed more efficient as fewer request/response cycles are needed, nevermind allocation.  However, sometimes there's just too much data to process, and that's why you would likely still want a loop.  This is especially true if you use `XConvertSelection` and need to deal with the *INCR* property as it means there's a lot of data for the display server to send.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this myself, ended up using [`XGetTextProperty`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/XGetTextProperty.html) instead (much more clean and reliable).

```c
int get_window_title(Window window, XTextProperty *wm_name)
{
    int found = XGetTextProperty(local.dpy, window, wm_name, local.netatoms[NET_WM_NAME]) &&
                wm_name->nitems;
    return found ? found : XGetTextProperty(local.dpy, window, wm_name, local.wmatoms[WM_NAME]);
}
```

https://github.com/lycuid/cluless/blob/e00bd1e3/src/cluless/core.c#L142